# selected gridview, populate a gridview with a nested gridview. doesnt work. helppp

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have 3 gridviews

1st gridview enable selection, which will populate the 2nd gridview if it has any data.

while the 3rd gridview is nested inside the 2nd gridview.

However, the 3rd gridview never ever show any single data..
What am i missing?

I can achieve this if the 2nd gridview is populated on the page load.
here is the code
im on asp.net c#

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="SurveyID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SurveyID" HeaderText="SurveyID" 
                SortExpression="SurveyID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SurveyTitle" HeaderText="SurveyTitle" 
                SortExpression="SurveyTitle" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [SurveyID], [SurveyTitle] FROM [Survey]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="QuestionID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionID" HeaderText="QuestionID" 
                InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="QuestionID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionTitle" HeaderText="QuestionTitle" 
                SortExpression="QuestionTitle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AnswerType" HeaderText="AnswerType" 
                SortExpression="AnswerType" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="ResultID">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ResultID" HeaderText="ResultID" 
                                SortExpression="ResultID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionID" HeaderText="QuestionID" 
                                SortExpression="QuestionID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="AnswerValue" HeaderText="AnswerValue" 
                                SortExpression="AnswerValue" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Results] WHERE ([QuestionID] = @QuestionID)">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionID" Type="Int32" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [QuestionID], [QuestionTitle], [AnswerType] FROM [Question] WHERE ([SurveyID] = @SurveyID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="SurveyID" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Show what you've tried. http://stackoverflow.com/faq Is this VB.NET or C#?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `AutoPostBack="True"` on `GridView1`, so that it posts back if the user selected a row. But I'm not familiar with  `SqlDataSource`. So i would set `GridView2`'s DataSource property in the `SelectedIndexChanged` handler and then `DataBind` it.

If you want to bind the data to the inner's grid when `GridView2` is bound, you should handle the [RowDataBound event](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx&ei=qJrwToCuDoueOsaAtbMB&usg=AFQjCNFLiXVmUYdeipjo17FOx0qggD2ZAw&sig2=FSF42laBuhi1ylMi87GQ3g) of `GridView2`, find the inner grid there, set it's datasource and databind it.

```
void GridView2_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    var rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
    var GridView3 = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GridView3");
    //set it's DataSource according to this row's DataItem
  }
}
```

Comment: i will give it a shot. however, just putting the autopostback true doesnt affect though since it is already postback when u click on the link button.